# How can I extract the Foursquare url location from Swarm webpage in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, foursquare, swarm

suppose we have this swarm url "https://www.swarmapp.com/c/dZxqzKerUMc" how we can get the url under Apple Williamsburg hyperlink in link above.

I tried to filter it out according to html tags but there are many  tags and lots of foursquare.com links.
below is a part of source code of the given link above

```
<h1><strong>Kristin Brooks</strong> at <a 
href="https://foursquare.com/v/apple-williamsburg/57915fa838fab553338ff7cb" 
target="_blank">Apple Williamsburg</a></h1>
```

the url foursquare in the code not always the same, so what is the best way to get that specific url uniquely for every given Swarm url.

I tried this:

```
import bs4
import requests

def get_4square_url(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    link = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in 
soup.select('a[href=https://foursquare.com/v/*]')]
    return link

print (get_4square_url('https://www.swarmapp.com/c/dZxqzKerUMc'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://foursquare.com/v/ as a pattern to get the desirable url

```
def get_4square_url(link):
    try:
        response = requests.get(link)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        for elem in soup.find_all('a', 
href=re.compile('https://foursquare\.com/v/')): #here is my pattern
            link = elem['href']
        return link
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError or 
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError or requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout \
            or urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
        pass
```